# List index out of range in lists and matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am a beginner to programming. I always encounter this problem for matrices. Please help me to correct this code and understand the concept behind this. Thank you.

```
def new_matrix(matrix_size, center_num):
    c = matrix_size / 2
    if matrix_size % 2 != 0:
        p = matrix_size
        print("enter a valid size for matrix")
    else:
        matrix = [[0] * matrix_size for z in range(matrix_size)]
        for counting in range(center_num, (matrix_size ** 2) + center_num):
            for i in range(2, matrix_size+1):
                row = int(c)
                column = int(c)
                if (i % 2 == 0):
                    for k in range(1, i + 1):  # moving right
                        column += 1
                        matrix[column][row] = counting
                    for k in range(1, i + 1):  # moving up
                        row += 1
                        matrix[column][row] = counting
                else:
                    for k in range(1, i + 1):  # moving left
                        column -= 1
                        matrix[column][row] = counting
                    for k in range(1, i + 1):  # moving down
                        row -= 1
                        matrix[column][row] = counting
        print(matrix)


new_matrix(6, 2)
```

Comment: and what is your desired output ?

Comment: First show a [mcve] with the error you get, then do you know python indexing is 0 to n-1, not 1 to n?

Answer (score -1):

This issue here seems to be that your indexing is off. The end value in `range(n)` is `n-1`, which means that in your for loop when `i = matrix_size` and then you try to increment the column beyond this, you're trying to assign a value to an index in the matrix that doesn't exist.

You can either try and fix your loop, i.e. reduce it by one, or you can do something like the following,

```
try:
    <your code goes here>
except IndexError:
    pass
```

And then anytime the loop hits an index error it will skip that index and try the next. It's better to fix the code though!